# Speed up INSERT statement

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have created a php app which creates records for the given employee for entire year.
My app takes Following input:
[image: Application]
I have used following code.

```
<?php
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$timeofdeparture="00-00-00";          
$timeofattendance="00-00-00";
$absent="Absent";
$startdate = '2015-01-01';              
$end_date ='2016-01-01';                
include 'config.php'; 
while (strtotime($startdate) <= strtotime($end_date))
{
    $flag=2;
    $sql2="INSERT INTO attendance(emp, dateofattendance, status,flag,timeofattendance,timeofdeparture)VALUES('$name', '$startdate', '$absent','$flag','$timeofattendance','$timeofdeparture') ";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    $startdate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));
}  
?>
```

But This Makes my App Slow as it takes a lot time to insert all the records for an year. is there any efficient way to optimize this operation?  All I want to do here is when administrator clicks on "add user" Button then his one year records must be created.After one year I can use this script again. or can we optimize this query to insert records for upto 3 years?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a transaction. Use parameterized queries. Have a drink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like this

```
        $sql2 =" INSERT INTO attendance(emp, dateofattendance, status,flag,timeofattendance,timeofdeparture)VALUES ";
            $sql_values = '';
            while (strtotime($startdate) <= strtotime($end_date))
            {
                $flag=2;
               $sql_values .=" ('$name', '$startdate', '$absent','$flag','$timeofattendance','$timeofdeparture') ,";

                $startdate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));
            }  
$sql2 = $sql2.$sql_values;
    if($sql_values){
             $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        }
```